# React Component with dynamic Sub-Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I`m creating a react dynamic dialog where you can add functionality to the Dialog.

One way of doing this was with Composition, but I did not manage to do this via composition.

I`m not very experienced on React, so this was my first approach

I got my Modal component, and the modal has

```
export default class KneatModal extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
     open: false
  }
  this.components = [];
```

I would add components like this

```
import CommentField from '../../../Modal/ModalContents/CommentField.jsx'

export default class DoApprove extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
}

componentDidMount() {
 this._buildDialog();
}

_buildDialog() {
  console.log("Building the Dialog"); 
  this.modal.components.push(CommentField);
}
```

In that modal renderer, i have

`<ModalContent components={ this.components } />`

Then i the final renderer in `ModalContent` i try to render all attached components

```
 render() {
  var list = this.props.components.map((Component, key) => <Component/> ); 
  return (
     <div className='modal-contents'>
        {list}
     </div>
 )
```

}

But the render method does not seems to work, i`ve tryed callin Component.render() instead of the component tag, but still could not make the sub-components render. =(

Would apreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: You push the CommetField into this.modal.components, then in the modal renderer you pass this.components.

Comment: Its correct. The modal is holding the component list, so it will pass this.components to the ModalContents (witch is inside the modal as well)
sorry if this was not that clear.

Comment: This is all kinds of wrong. **All kinds**. No offense. Post the full code of each component so we can correct all of it.

Comment: Posted all 4 components code. as they currently are (im changing to test it out)

Answer (score 0):

To be even more specific, this resumes on what im attempting

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent1 from './MyComponent1.jsx'
import MyComponent2 from './MyComponent2.jsx'

export default class KneatModalContent extends React.Component {

   constructor() {
      super();
      this.components = [MyComponent1, MyComponent2];
   }

   render() {
     return (
     <div className='modal-contents'>
        {this.components.map(function (component, i) {
           return <{ component } key= { i } />
        })}
     </div>
 )
}

}
```